# How fast can hyperdrive-equipped Star Wars vessels travel?

Tags: science-fiction, star-wars

Throughout Star Wars, references are made to "hyperdrives", "hyperspace" and "lightspeed". It seems nearly all spacecraft are equipped with hyperdrives, and are as such capable of making the jump. But how fast is that?

Assuming the Galaxy far, far away is roughly the size of the Milky Way, traveling between two planets on opposite sides would mean crossing roughly 100,000 light years, which takes light 100,000 years. That seems a bit long for a trip. Is there any canon information stating roughly how fast you can travel with a hyperdrive? Maybe the distance between two planets/moons and how long the trip took?

Comment: Let's face it: Star Trek = Real Science and Star Wars = Fake Science.  This is the true essence of the decades-long battle between the two factions of fans. And the reason Trekkies are geeks while Star Wars fans (they don't even have a kewl name...) are just dorks.  The Millenium Falcon made the Kessel Run in less than 12 PARSECS.  'nuff said.

Comment: @JohnnyBones but Hyperspace is star trek's Slipstream and/or transwarp and a hundred other sci-fi methods of travel. And the Parsec thing is easy to explain. He took a dangerous shortcut. Judging a path by distance is just as valid as judging it by time it takes to navigate.

Comment: @JohnnyBones You're welcome to your opinions on which is better, personally I like them both but your comment glosses over the reality that Trek is just as happy to make crap up, so calling Star Trek "real science" is a bit much.

Comment: @cde - Ah, yes.  The old "shortcut" excuse.  But, you see, Solo was responding to a question about the Falcon's *speed*.  ;o)  Of course, my whole comment was just having a bit of fun, but there's also an element of truth in it.  Roddenberry invented the cell phone, tablets and video conferencing, just to name a few things.  Lucas has given us...?

Comment: @JohnnyBones speed is required to safely and successfully avoid being pulled into a mass shadow. A gravity slingshot doesn't work well if you go in at the wrong speed or angle.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of which is better (which is subjective) but the different intents of the two franchises.  Star Wars was inspired by space opera, and concerned largely with mythological aspects of story.  (To Lucas' great credit, Star Wars is primarily focused on deep character development over a series of films, which is probably part of why they have so much resonance.) Star Trek rooted in "hard science fiction" where the creators  are partly concerned with having some degree of scientific credibility.

Comment: @JohnnyBones _"Lucas has given us...?"_ pod-racing! Frankly, I'm surprised you've forgotten. :-)

Comment: @JohnnyBones Hyperspace is faster than warp 9 and **much** faster than warp 9. Saying Star Trek is “real” science isn’t true, not like we actually have “warp speed”. Btw parsecs are a *real* thing that is actually used in science. It’s a distance, not a time. It’s impressive because he got close to a black hole.

Comment: @YourSleepParalysisDemon - I think what Johnnybones has facetiously implied is that there is hard researched real science theory behind warp drives called Alcubierre warp drives. Experiments have been carried out on this theory as of the 1990s. While hyperspace and hyperdrive are still relegated to science-fiction. While both methods of transport were originally fiction plot devices, one has proven more thought out and science based than the other. The same can be said of Heinlein, Asimov, Clarke et.al. before they received the Hollywood treatment. Where as Star Wars is a western in space.

Answer (score 10):

There is a severe lack of technical data on Hyperspace travel in the Canon Star Wars universe. Even the expanded old canon isn't that detailed on it. Too busy focusing on space sword fights I guess. [As noted on Wiki though](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspace_(science_fiction)#Star_Wars):

> In any case, hyperspace is an extremely fast method of travel, as Obi-Wan and Luke Skywalker's journey from Tatooine to Alderaan is theorized to have only taken two days maximum, whereas these two planets are separated by half a galaxy or more. **Darth Maul took approximately seven hours to travel from Coruscant to Tatooine.**

[image]

As seen on this map (***click to enlarge***), Coruscant is 9/10,K/L, and Tatooine is 16,R. A quarter of the galaxy in hours. The U.S.S. Voyager (Star Trek, more realistic) took **years** for a similar path using multiple tricks.

Of course, Hyperspace isn't a direct/linear travel path, and most travel through it goes through pre-charted travel lanes due to the danger. Some travel, though shorter distances in real space, take much longer because you have to navigate around hyperspace hazards. Like driving around a bad neighborhood.

Comment: omg, I would love to have a high def version of this map so I can more easily make out all the names

Comment: @DForck42 click on it for higher res. Or Google image search for star wars galaxy map.

Comment: That's one tiny-ass galaxy though...

Comment: @DukeZhou More like very few notable planets and moons. It makes sense that intelligent life forms are few and far in between, so while there could well be billions of planets in the galaxy, only these few are significant enough to make the map

Comment: Case in point, Jakku and Star Killer Base arnt in it. Or Illium.

Comment: @DForck42 here is your hi-res (or better res) map: https://i.imgur.com/hNhJaqc.jpg (3000x4100). And DukeZhou maybe that only shows planets that have been mapped/discovered? It could be larger than the milky way. This is evident by the left hand side, as it is a large 1/2 of the galaxy unknown regions, i.e. not mapped. For instance, find Mandalore, and see the Mandalorian space bubble. In Clone Wars it is said that Mandalore is the main world for a number of worlds (that the Death Watch wanted to control after the Maul plot). So one can extrapolate that in that bubble there are many worlds. Thu